# WPF - Lock Grid (Container) Star Size

Tags: c#, wpf, grid-layout

Is there anyway a Star Sized Grid.Row or Grid.Height specified value can be locked?

take my current wip for example:

[image]

How or What do i do to keep the equivalent value of 1* that is allocated for Row 0 (Index) be kept even if i set a different star size values for Row 1 ~ 3?

My allocation keeps braking up as it can't be helped for me to change values as the ui development progresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use 2 Grids. Outer Grid will have rows `1*` and `3*`. Nested Grid can be places in `3*` row and can have its own RowsDefinitions with different proportions:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition/>
      <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: @Nii, it is not a hack, it is a feature. Nested panels are very common. More nested panels mean more complex composite/hierarchical layout. And also panels/controls can overlap on any level.